# How to uninstall rEFInd (0.8.2) on Yosemite

Tags: efi

I'd like to remove rEFInd, since my laptop doesn't wake up from suspension (provided that the laptop is only powered by battery) anymore eversince I installed it (in neither of the operating systems: Mac OS and Ubuntu).

Assuming one has installed rEFInd on the main hard drive, then according to rEFInd's page it should be enough to remove (important: also empty the trash) the following folder:

```
/EFI/refind
```

http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#uninstalling

Indeed my blessed folder is that one:

```
Mac:~ user$ bless --info
finderinfo[0]: XXXXXXXX => Blessed System Folder is /EFI/refind
finderinfo[1]: XXXXXXXX => Blessed System File is /EFI/refind/refind_x64.efi
finderinfo[2]:      0 => Open-folder linked list empty
finderinfo[3]:      0 => No alternate OS blessed file/folder
finderinfo[4]:      0 => Unused field unset
finderinfo[5]: XXXXXXXX => OS X blessed folder is /EFI/refind
64-bit VSDB volume id:  0xXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Mac:~ user$ bless --info --getBoot
/dev/disk0s2
```

Now my question is, do I have to remove just the `refind` folder, or also the `EFI` folder? Since my `EFI` folder also contains a `tools` folder. Here's the entire folder tree:

```
EFI
   - refind
       - icons
       - keys
       - refind_x64.efi
       - refind.conf
   - tools
       - gptsync_x63.efi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `gptsync_x64.efi` program file was *probably* installed with rEFInd, but is a separate program. Leaving it in place should do no harm, but will also probably do no good, so it's a judgment call on your part. If you remove rEFInd, chances are the only thing that would run `gptsync_x64.efi` would be a subsequent install of rEFInd (or of its predecessor, rEFIt) or launching it manually from an EFI shell.